# EOF Exception in java while sending multiple files through single socket connection

Tags: java, sockets, networking, serversocket, eofexception

I'm trying to send multiple files over java sockets. After successfully receiving first file, it throws EOFexception. I am unable to figure out what's going wrong. (All files are successfully sent from sender's side)

Sender's code :

```
    sendToServer = new Socket(receiver,port);
    DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(sendToServer.getOutputStream());

    for(File f: file_to_send){

        sendMessage = f.getName() + "\n"+ f.length() + "\n";
        out.writeUTF(sendMessage);

        FileInputStream requestedfile = new FileInputStream(f.getPath());
        System.out.println("file path: "+f.getPath());

        int count;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
        while ((count = requestedfile.read(buffer)) > 0)
        {
            out.write(buffer, 0, count);
        }

        System.out.println("File transfer completed!! voila! :)");
        requestedfile.close();
    }

    out.close();
    sendToServer.close();
```

Receiver's code :

```
System.out.println("File Count : " + fileCount);
for (int count =0; count<fileCount; count++){
            String fileName = dis.readUTF();
            int length = Integer.parseInt(fileName.split("\n")[1]);
            fileName = fileName.split("\n")[0];
            System.out.println("File Name : " + fileName);
            System.out.println("Length : " + length);
            System.out.println("File Data : ");
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(fileName));
            int c;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
            while ((c = dis.read(buffer)) > 0)
            {
                fos.write(buffer, 0, c);
                fos.flush();
            }
            fos.close();
            System.out.println("\nFile received successfully!!! voila !! :)");               
        }
```

And the output is like this :

```
Files Count : 2
File Name : Belly Dance.3gp
Length : 15969978
File Data : 

File received successfully!!! voila !! :)
java.io.EOFException
at java.base/java.io.DataInputStream.readUnsignedShort(DataInputStream.java:345)
at java.base/java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:594)
at java.base/java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:569)
at App.java.DiscoveryClient.HandleInputMessage(DiscoveryClient.java:130)
at App.java.DiscoveryClient.run(DiscoveryClient.java:44)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code that receives the file does not stop after reading the first file, but keeps reading until the end of the stream, writing everything that's sent to the same file.

You need to keep track of how many bytes you've already read and/or how many bytes you still have to read:

```
        int remainingBytes = length;
        while (remainingBytes > 0 && (c = dis.read(buffer, 0, Math.min(buffer.length, remainingBytes))) > 0)
        {
            remainingBytes -= c;
            fos.write(buffer, 0, c);
            // fos.flush(); this is not really necessary
        }
```

By the way, using `int` for file length limits you to files of at most 2GB. If this is a problem, use `long` instead of `int`.

Comment: Never flush inside the loop. It eliminates the benefit of any output buffering that may be in place.